Old animated show / movie where the main character spun a knife to pick a direction
I apologise beforehand for the lack of clear details, but I'm looking for an animated show or perhaps a movie (if so, probably in a series) of which I remember only 1 thing for sure:
At the end of it, the protagonist (probably a young man / boy) placed his magic knife (simple looking but probably important) on a rock and spun it, to decide in what direction to travel. Not sure if it was a common occurrence but it seemed like something he would do at the end of every episode.
Now things that I am not 100% sure:

It could be a fantasy or post-apocalyptic setting. The main character could be dressed as a barbarian or a native American.

I remember the landscape to be desolate, lacking vegetation, and feeling lonely. The protagonist seemed to always travel alone.

The animation and the tone seemed serious, and might be Western made.


I was born in the 1980s and watched this thing on Spanish TV (but most likely not made in Spain)

I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to have Science Fiction or Fantasy elements.

is it the animated show, pirates of dark water ?

@MeatTrademark magic knife is not a fantasy element?

Magic knife, dressed like native american or barbarian, desolate world... This could be anime called Triton of the Sea. Please check it.

@joistorm Before edit: "probably important knife in some way, perhaps magical?" Not very convincing.

@MeatTrademark the protagonist is probably a young man and magic knife is probably important. Knife is not probably magic, knife is certainly magic but its importance is uncertain.

If you are the OP, you should merge your accounts. If not, how do you know this?

Rahan? Préhistoric setting, and the wandering hero would usually spin his knife to pick a new direction to explore.

@MeatTrademark How do I know what? By carefully reading and parsing the sentence that OP has written. I am not OP.

It IS "Rahan", specifically the 1987 series. And it's very different from what I remembered, obviously. Thanks a lot everybody for your help!
